# Laravel RESTful API authentication for mobile app

Tags: php, android, laravel, authentication, restful-authentication

I would like to discuss what is the best way to secure your API's in order to be used from a mobile application.

Since there is not third-party I guess OAuth is not a good choice?
Would JWT be a good choice?

The hard part for me to understand is how can I authenticate so I can protect the data in my API's unless someone is authorized to call them.

I use Laravel 5.1 in server side and the mobile application that I want to call the API's is an android one.

I hope that I didn't forget to mention any important information.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Basic authentication is probably the easiest way to secure your API.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is it worth implementing though? I mean in terms of quality since it is the easiest way.

Comment: @csdinos now i have same question. i think jwt is not so good for mobile applications because tokens invalidate automatically by server after one hour and user should login again and again, it's ok for web applications but in android it's not a good idea to show login page more than one time! i think just one login process is enough for mobiles apps! what do you think? did you use jwt for authenticating users in your android app?

Comment: @AliSherafat
Truth is that you can actually change the lifespan of the tokens in JWT so that wouldn't be a problem I think. I am not entirely sure what's the best practice here but I ended up with **OAuth2.0** using the **Resource owner credentials grant**. 
I used _lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel_ package: [link](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/)

Answer (score 1):

## Use OAuth2

Consider using OAuth 2 with Client Credentials Grant.

You can request an access token using your Client's credentials.

- [Client Credentials Grant](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2/grants/credentials.html)

Use OAuth 2 Server Laravel:

- [lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/)

Implementing an Authorization Server with the Client Credentials Grant using Luca's package:

- [Implementing Client Credentials Grant](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/blob/master/docs/authorization-server/client-credentials.md)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one question. Given that the user's **credentials should not be stored** in the android side, what is the best **life span** of the access token?

Comment: @csdinos I think that's up to your application needs. Is it OK for the app to ask for a token every day? There's no good content regarding that topic. I've seen API's like this: http://docs.apigee.com/api-services/content/oauth-20-client-credentials-grant-type#configuringflowsandpolicies-configuretheflowwithapolicy using 40 days life span.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at 
[JSON Web Token Authentication for Laravel & Lumen](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth)

It provides security and protection to data and routes.

Comment: Yes I have already stumbled upon this one. The idea is to authenticate the one who calls the API through tokens right? 
Two questions that I have:
1) Should the data be a part of the token or just use it for authentication?
2) In the API call where you actually do the authentication and pass the token to the 'caller', you just secure it (username,password) through HTTPS or something?

Comment: `JWT is used both for authentication and data protection. take a look at https://stormpath.com/blog/jwt-the-right-way`